# How to include/ link other .cs (C#) files to my web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, extends, inheritance

I have something like this:

- C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop\MyProject **(includes a solution file)** \Sample **(includes a project file)**
- C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop\MyProject **(includes a solution file)** \Sample\src **(includes  Request.cs file)**\web **(includes web page stuff)**

  - **folder 'web' contents:**
  - Default.aspx
  - Default.aspx.cs

Lets say I have a **String sayHello = "Hello";** in **Request.cs** file.

 How could I "take" that string to my web page (into Default.aspx.cs file)?

regards,

user1223227

Comment: Can you please explain more, the details you mention in teh question is too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi user1223227 (stop me if I'm getting too personal).

If you mean how to reuse code between projects or solutions, then you want to create a [Class Library](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dll12222005064058AM/dll.aspx) project with the common code, and reference that project (or the assembly that the project produces) in both projects that require that code.

Alternatively, if you wish to reference the same physical source file in two or more projects, then you can [add the file as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx).

Comment: That's (creating a Class Lib project) exactly what I want, thank you.

Comment: @devdigital: +1 for the _"stop me if I'm getting too personal"_ stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

try to think in terms of runtime objects rather than compile time files. You would need to have a reference to an object (e.g. of type Request) to access its members(E.g sayHello). Then the question becomes how can I get a reference to a Request object. The simple answer is new `Request(...)` that however requires that the code location knows of the type `Request` you might have to reference either the assembly that includes the Request type of reference the project where the Request type is defined.